# Amazon S3 URL Encoding

Tags: amazon-s3, url-encoding

If I have a file name that is

`a'd1 & "[tttt]" + 'sq.jpg`

When this gets uploaded to Amazon S3, it gets converted to this

`a'd1 & %22[tttt]%22 + 'sq.jpg`

So the double quotes are URL encoded and the filename itself is changed.

The file has to be fetched using the encoded URL

`a%27d1+%26+%2522%5Btttt%5D%2522+%2B+%27sq.jpg`

So the encoding rules seem to be:

```
": %2522  (double encoded)
Space: + 
&: %26 
[: %5B
]: %5D
+: %2B
```

Is there a way to determine all the rules that S3 requires? Normal javascript encoding with (encodeURI or even encodeURIComponent) won't work

Comment: > "When this gets uploaded to Amazon S3, it gets converted to this"

_How_ did you upload it? It's quite possible that there is a bug in the tool you used.

Comment: why do you say that `encodeURIComponent` won't work? as far as I can see the onyl difference that and between what you're describing is that `encodeURIComponent` encodes space as %20. However, %20 also works with s3 so I don't see any problem using it

Answer (score 7):

This is not from a definitive source, but it has worked for my requirements: [encodeS3URI](https://github.com/GeorgePhillips/node-s3-url-encode/blob/master/index.js)

It replaces the following characters `+!"#$&'()*+,:;=?@`

S3 replaces spaces in filepaths with `+`, so its best to do the URI encoding before any further string replacements

Comment: Just to highlight this again, if you upload it with spaces it changes to + if you then later come back and upload it with + it changes it to %2B